# JQuery function keyup does not work on my project and other functions work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i do not know why this code does not work if i key up any character the value of input show

```
 <div>
   <input class="form-control live" name="name" placeholder="Item Name" 
            data-class="live-title" required/>
 </div>

 $('.live').keyup(function () {
    $($(this).data('class')).text($(this).val());
 });

 <div class="card cats">
   <span class='price-tag'>$<span class="live-price">0</span></span>
   <img class='' src='' alt=''/>
   <div class='card-body'>
       <h5 class='live-title'>title</h5>
       <p class='live-desc'>Description</p>
       <p class='live-country'>Country</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's not in a script tag?

Comment: Also `$($(this).data('class'))` is going to evaluate to `$('live-title')` which is an invalid selector.

Comment: You should also consider using the 'input' event, rather than keyup, as keyup will trigger on buttons such as arrow buttons, which do not change the value of the input.  `input` only triggers if the value actually changes.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).data('class')` will be `live-title`.So in order to select a dom which have this class you need to prefix it with class selector using dot (`.`)

```js
$('.live').keyup(function() {
  $("." + $(this).data('class')).text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="form-control live" name="name" placeholder="Item Name" data-class="live-title" required/>
</div>


<div class="card cats">
  <span class='price-tag'>$<span class="live-price">0</span></span>
  <img class='' src='' alt='' />
  <div class='card-body'>
    <h5 class='live-title'>title</h5>
    <p class='live-desc'>Description</p>
    <p class='live-country'>Country</p>
  </div>
</div>
```